# Import specific row from access database

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, textbox

at current I have 5 TextBoxes that I wish to populate from the first 5 rows of a column in an Access Database.

I have attempted several different SQL queries, with no success.

Here's my working code for the first box:

```
Try
    Dim con As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Test\Response.mdb;")
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand
    con.Open()
    cmd.Connection = con
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM question"
    cmd.Prepare()
    Dim Trace = cmd.ExecuteReader
    With Trace
        .Read()
        q1txt.Text = .Item("questiontext")
        .Close()
    End With
Catch
End Try
```

That code works perfectly fine, however when I try to expand on this to include the next 4, I can't get it to work or find any information that can help me.

I've tried writing a diffrent query to populate each box using

```
select * from question limit n-1, 1
```

and

```
select top 1 field from question
```

Amongst dozens of others that all throw up one exception or another.

Does anyone know of a way to alter my code so I can effectively tell it:

```
SELECT TOP 5 FROM question
q1txt.Text = .item("ROW1")
q2txt.Text = .item("ROW2")
q3txt.Text = .item("ROW3")
q4txt.Text = .item("ROW4")
q5txt.Text = .item("ROW5")
```

Thank you to Steve for helping me out with this! The code that I am now using is here:

```
Dim boxes = {q1txt, q2txt, q3txt, q4txt, q5txt}
Dim index As Integer = 0
Using con = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Test\Response.mdb;")
    Using cmd = New OleDbCommand("SELECT TOP 5 * FROM question", con)
        con.Open()
        Using Trace = cmd.ExecuteReader
            For Each item In boxes
                With Trace
                    .Read()
                    boxes(index).Text = .Item("questiontext")
                    index += 1
                End With
            Next
        End Using
    End Using
End Using
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access doesn't have a LIMIT keyword like MySql. You could ORDER BY on some column and take the TOP 5 columns. I don't know if you have any kind of column that can be ordered, so I show code without an ORDER BY clause but fetching the first 5 records in whichever order the database give them

```
Dim boxes = new TextBox() {q1Text, q2Text, q3Text, q4Text, q5Text }

Dim index As Integer = 0
Using con = New OleDbConnection(".....")
Using cmd = New OleDbCommand("SELECT TOP 5 * FROM question", con)
    con.Open()
    Using Trace = cmd.ExecuteReader
       While Trace.Read()
         boxes(index).Text = Trace.Item("questiontext")
         index += 1
       End While
    End Using
End Using
End Using
```

At every Read you have a different record to place in a different TextBox, so I have built an array of your textboxes and used an index to fill the correct box

Notice also that I have added the Using Statement around your disposable objects to be sure they are correctly closed and disposed

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realise you could do that. However it hasn't worked... it only populates the first box. I've edited the code by adding "For Each item in boxes" just after .Read() but this populates all 5 with the top Field.

Comment: Ah, got it working! Thank you again. Will post the working code above.

Comment: Fixed, forget to loop over the Reader

Comment: That code works perfectly now, thank you. I can remove my For Each. Much appreciated!

Comment: Well, I should warn you that this code is really locked to the number of controls and number of rows to be retrieved. (Don't forget to add a new control to the array if you change the TOP X value). If you ever need to change that I suggest to use a better suited control like a DataGridView

Comment: Thank you again, I certainly want it locked to those 5 results. I'll have a look at DataGridView for future reference.